# Highcharts Tooltip pointFormat and formatter

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to get the following output in highcharts...
Have a list of supporting values for a specific point and show in the tooltip all of those supporting values on that single point.

my solution is to use the formatter()

```
formatter: function () {
   var res = 'The value for <b>' + this.x + '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b><br/>';

   for(var i = 0; i < this.point.supportingData.list.length; i++){
      res += this.point.supportingData.list[i].name + '<br/>';
   }
   return res;
}
```

example.... point (x,y) has 12, 17, 53 and 27
I want all of those valuse to appear on the hover over on point (x,y).

The problem is that I want my formatter to be split like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/207xt4an/

Where the x value is on the bottom of the chart and everything else that comes with that jsfiddle.

Is there a way to accomplish this using formatter? Or vise versa, grab all of the supporting in the pointFormat?

Comment: You want it exactly like that `formatter` you've included, right? What about that doesn't work in your example?

Comment: You should be able to use pointFormatter for formatting displayed value in your tooltip. http://jsfiddle.net/207xt4an/2/ You can use tooltip.split for splitting your tooltip. I am not sure how you would like your chart to look so it will help us when you will post live example of your chart, like jsFiddle.

Comment: pointFormatter worked perfectly! I added that and it worked :). Thanks for the update on the jsfiddle! I was trying to use formatter instead of pointFormatter. If you put this as an answer I will accept it :)